# Convert excel formula to DAX / M

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am trying to work out if this is possible or not in DAX or M.

Basically I want to replicate this:

=IF(T9>0,T9-1,$Q$6)

Which is the formula in T10.  So it is counting down by one if the value above it is not 0, otherwise put in a value and start counting down again.

Here is some data and expected outcome:

[image]

When the stock on hand drops below 5000 it triggers the lead time count down to start.  When that hits 0, it adds stock to the SOH balance, 4000 in this case.  Since the stock is below its reorder point, it puts starts the countdown again.

Comment: Excel and PBI's DAX are two very different things, in DAX everything revolves around context and there is no concept of previous or next cell like we have in Excel. But since you didn't share anything about the data and asked the question very casually, all I can say is add an index column in Power Query and then use the somewhat similar logic.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  If you need some assistance with your code, please supply a sample of data, expected outcome given that data, and the code you have tried. Actually, in M, you can just develop a List that will return that series.

Answer (score 0):

We would need the data in order to answer your question properly, if you can't share the dataset, add the index column using

> Transform data > Add Column > Index Column